# Dynamically populate value from object into apex chart (stacked)

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com, report-chart

In **X-axis** there will be 3 type of **Customer Type Positive, Negative, Neutral** and **Y-axis** is the total no of customer under each agent.

**Following is the expected value which i need to plot in apex chart from object**-

[image]

**X-Axis -(FYI)**

[image]

**How i have to construct class or page for populating below values so that under mouse over of each bar in positive it will show number of customer under each agent?**

Please advise

Comment: Are you looking for chartTips??? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_chartTips.htm

Comment: I need to know the code structure, how i will construct the class and wrapper class